# ArgumentError (Unsupported argument type: 0 (Integer)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack, geocoder, geocomplete

My search form looks for an object in the database based on the address field.
Everything works fine if i search only for the city name, for example Milan, but the search breaks if a select the complete google maps address suggested via  maps Api.
For example "metropolitan city of Milan" or some address "Via Paolo Sarpi, Milano, Metropolitan City of Milan, Italy"
I got:

```
ArgumentError in PagesController#search
Unsupported argument type: 0 (Integer)

        
    app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:14:in `search'
    Started GET "/search?search=Via+Paolo+Sarpi%2C+Milano%2C+Metropolitan+City+of+Milan%2C+Italy&start_date=&end_date=&commit=Search" for ::1 at 2020-07-16 15:13:19 +0200
    Processing by PagesController#search as HTML
      Parameters: {"search"=>"Via Paolo Sarpi, Milano, Metropolitan City of Milan, Italy", "start_date"=>"", "end_date"=>"", "commit"=>"Search"}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 243ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1931)
```

Im using geocoder, **ransack** gem and **geocomplete** script.

schema.rb

```
t.string "location"
```

home

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Where are you going?", class: "form-control" , id:"autolocation"%>
...
$(function () {
    jQuery("#autolocation").geocomplete();
  });
```

page_controller

```
    class PagesController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def search
    if params[:search].present? && params[:search].strip !=""
      session[:loc_search] = params[:search]
    end

....

if session[:loc_search] && session[:loc_search] != ""
     *@cars_address = Car.where(active: true).near(session[:loc_search], 5, order:* 'distance')
   else
     @cars_address = Car.where(active: true).all
   end
.....
```

Comment: Please include the whole stacktrace.

Comment: In addition to showing the whole stack trace, I'm not sure how to correlate your error message info to the `page_controller.rb` file. The error message shows a hash, but it doesn't include the `loc_search` key that is used in the shown snippet of code from the controller. Does the snippet contain line 14?

Comment: The code which you pasted for `page_controller` is not for search. Paste the complete error and code